# Larger search bar in iOS 11? How to opt-into new style?

Tags: ios, uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, ios11

I noticed that in the App Store app, the `UISearchBar` they're using is larger. (see attached) — Currently when I compile for iOS 11b9 using Xcode 9b6, it still uses the old style, **which is too small and is clipped by the status bar**.

Is there some clean way to enable/mimic this larger variant of `UISearchBar`, while still maintaining backwards compatibility with older iOS versions?

[image: iOS 11 larger search bar in App Store]

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I'm asking *how* to do something specific. If I already knew the method I wouldn't be posting a question.

Comment: Did you use the new way of setting the `navigationItem.searchController`?

Comment: @matt doesn't that put the search bar *below* the title on the underlying navigation bar? that's not what we want... we want it to float over it with the cancel button.

Comment: You're perfectly right about that. But it's what they want you to do in iOS 11. — Anyway, I've told you what I'm doing to solve this. Your question would be a lot better if you'd show what _you_ are doing.

Comment: @matt We're doing the classic method of presenting the `UISearchController` model, which now displays incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

I did find after the iPhone X announcement (and subsequent video additions to the Developer site) that there is a bit of a workaround necessarily: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/201

**For iOS 11+ only:**

1. Apply the `UISearchController` to the "navigationItem" not the `UIViewController` itself. Then set it to be "active" (= `true`).
2. Ensure this `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` is `true`.
3. Monitor the delegate callback to track when it was dismissed, and then **remove it from the "navigationItem"** until it's needed again.

... Honestly it seems like this was a bit of an afterthought, but it ***does work*** and is good enough for now.